# Mouse button doesn't work on laptop after liquid damage ... but only in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, laptop, mouse, water-damage

Silly me spilled coffee on my laptop (ThinkPad T61).  It wasn't a like literally pouring a stream of liquid onto it, but enough for me to remove the keyboard, palm rest and battery, and let it sit open and upside-down for a while.

Fortunately, it's my cheapo spare service laptop that I don't really need to depend on, but I have a peculiar issue now.  The only thing that doesn't work now is the left mouse buttons ... *but only in Windows?*

I can boot to USB Linux and everything works.  But how??

Comment: When you removed your keyboard, was the machine completely turned off, not plugged into the main or anything? If the left mouse button (BTW, by "mouse", do you mean "TouchPad", or actual USB mouse?) stopped functioning in Windows only, it might mean that a left mouse button function is disabled in Windows. If you go to Device Manager and disable the TouchPad (?), then restart the PC (you can do that without a mouse), and let Windows discover the hardware and install the driver again, what happens?

Comment: basic drivers i guess, Linux does not require a lot to run so maybe it only picks up a basic driver to be able to run your touchpad. 
Had a similar issue once, but with some isopropyl alcohol and a fine brush will help to get the coffee out

Comment: @Didier: yes, everything was powered off, unplugged, battery out, etc.  The left buttons for the touchpad and trackpoint are non-functional in Windows.  An external mouse works fine in any OS.